# Not Able To Implement Google Sign In for iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, google-signin

I am following all steps as per this link Click [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in)
After doing all steps it gives me [image: Errors for adding this code]

Can anyone tell me this strange is happening ?
Answer would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: In which class are you writing this code ? I means is it in your custom viewController or AppDelegate or somewhere else ?

Comment: It would be best if you post the code text instead of a screenshot. Also, please tell us where these lines have been placed for clarity.

Comment: have u added #import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
 framework properly?

Comment: Whatever you have suggested  @iDeveloper and guys I am very thankful of you but it didn't work so , Can anyone suggest me a complete Tutorial only with Objective-C And with  Facebook SDK v4.8. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Try those:

1. Add GIDSignIn library header properly, if in case you missing something.
2. Add AppDelgate.h file into your ViewController (If you not writing this code in AppDelegate.m)
3. Read point 4 which I copied from GitHub forum, which can be the main reason of your errors.
4. It looks like iOS 9 changed the constant UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey to  UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey. Dynamically support both, especially in Xcode 6.4 which doesn't recognize UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey.
5. After try these all if its still not working then comment here for further help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the AppDelegate.m file from which I implemented Google Signin SDK (the new one)

```
   #define kGoogleClientID @""

   #import "AppDelegate.h"
   #import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>

   @interface AppDelegate ()<GIDSignInDelegate>

   @end

   @implementation AppDelegate


   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

       [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kGoogleClientID;

      return YES;
    }

    - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    }

   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

   }

    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

   }

    - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {


   }

    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

   }



   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
         sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
       annotation:(id)annotation {

    if(annotation){
          NSDictionary *options = @{UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey: sourceApplication,
                                      UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey: annotation};
          return  [self application:application
                             openURL:url
                             options:options];
      }


    }




  /* Google */

    - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
     didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
 withError:(NSError *)error {
   // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
   // ...
  }


    - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn
   didDisconnectWithUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
 withError:(NSError *)error {
    // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
    // ...
   }

  @end
```

Hope this helps you out